# android studio spinner context: this compile error in java

Tags: android-fragments, android-spinner, android-context, android-studio-2.2

I'm trying to implement a simple spinner in android studio according to a bunch of examples I found online, and Gradle compile gives me an error on Context: this, and as I am novice android studio and java, I have no idea why,  there appears to be proper import statements, and code statements, so I do not know if this is a "tool" error meaning there is some kind of path statement or tools / project set up problem, or is this an actual coding problem?   Funny that import android.widget.Spinner;  is greyed out and tool saying "Unused import statement"{[image: importstatements picture]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLY9q.jpg) used when code all appears to be there?  any help would be appreciated,  the project is old so I am just modifying the code using the source and tools that were provided,  android studio 2.2 and api 23.

and here are the spinner related statements,

```
enter code here
    mSpinner = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.battery_chem_spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.battery_chemistry_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    mSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    mSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener((AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener) this);
```

[image: spinner statements picture]

and here is the error telling me the context this is not working?

Wrong 1st argument type. Found 'com.cypress.cysmart.BLEServiceFragments.BatteryStatusFragment', required. android.content.Context
[image]

Comment: well I see the answer to the first question import android.widget.Spinner is greyed out because there is two of the same statements

Comment: well I now see, answer to question 2 is perhaps replacing context: this, with getActivity(), somehow makes the compile error go away, no idea why? this is a learning experience

Comment: now app crashes with null pointer error when trying to display the page